# $scope.$watch only triggered once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-watch

I've set the following watcher in my controller:

```
var embeds = {twitter: false, facebook: false};

$scope.$watch(embeds, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if(embeds.twitter && embeds.facebook) $scope.loading = appLoader.off();
});
```

This should fire when `embeds` changes. I have the following functions that check if all my embedded Tweets and Facebook posts have loaded for the page. When all Tweets or Facebook posts are loaded, it updates `embeds` within a `$timeout` block in order to trigger a digest cycle.

```
checkFBInit();

twttr.ready(function(twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind('loaded', function(event) {
        $timeout(function() {
            embeds.twitter = true;
        });
    });
});

function checkFBInit() {
    // Ensure FB.init has been called before attempting to subscribe to event
    var fbTrys = 0;
    function init() {
        fbTrys++;
        if (fbTrys >= 60) {
            return;
        } else if (typeof(FB) !== 'undefined') {
            fbTrys = 60;
            FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    embeds.facebook = true;
                });
            });
            return;
        } else {
            init();
        };
    };
    init();
};
```

The problem I'm having is that my watcher only fires once when I set it. I've tried binding `embeds` to `$scope` and/or watching `embeds.twitter` and `embeds.facebook` but the watcher only ever fires once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
$scope.embeds = {twitter: false, facebook: false};
$scope.$watch('embeds', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if ($scope.embeds.twitter && $scope.embeds.facebook) {
        $scope.loading = appLoader.off();
    }
}, true);
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope. First argument must be `string` or `function` which return the name of param.

Comment: Upvoted your answer because it was half of the solution I needed. I realized after re-reading the docs for the second time that I need to also check for object equality by passing `true` as the 3rd argument to the watcher. Passing the variable to be watched to the watcher as a string was the other half of the problem. If you accept the edit I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used to work with angular a year ago and forget about this nuance :)